# Diagonal pixels of an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math

I have an image of size `30 x 100` pixels.

1. How can I count how many pixels are there on the diagonal? can I
   just apply the Pythagorean theorem? but if yes, we may obtain float
   number of pixels. So how can I address this issue?
2. In addition, how can I extract automatically the `x` and `y` coordinate values of
   each pixel on the diagonal?

I have written a MATLAB code for a square matrix which is very easy. But how can I generalize my code to include images of any size (not only square images)..

```
%suppose an image of size 100 x 100
image = rand(100,100);
n = length(image);

%extract how many pixels are there on the diagonal
diagonal_pixels = sqrt(n^2 + n^2);

%Get the x and y coordinates values of each diagonal pixel
for i = 1: n
x_coordinate_diag(i) = i;
y_coordinate_diag(i) = i;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use these steps to get the diagonal pixels

1. Get min width and height length (suppose it is the width)
2. Loop through the min lenght(ex: width)
3. get height cordinate by rounding i * height / width

For example 50 x 100

1. Min is 50
2. for i = 0, `j = 0 x 100 / 50 = 0`
3. for i = 1, `j = 1 x 100 / 50 = 2`
4. for i = 2, `j = 2 x 100 / 50 = 4`
5. ...
6. for i = 50, `j = 50 x 100 / 50 = 100`

Comment: Gracias! This is a good approach. I will see what I get and keep you updated!

Comment: do not forget to round the result to the lower value (1.9 become 1 and not 2)

Comment: This does not produce a continuous line. If you instead loop over the max length, you get the equivalent of the Bresenham line, which is the ideal, continuous line, between the two corners.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for your comment. Can you please explain that in detail in an answer and how to do this in MATLAB?  because I didn't understand well your remark. Thank you a lot

Comment: @Christina: what I’m saying is follow exactly this answer, but in step 2 iterate over the max length instead of the min length.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ok I see. Thank you for this remark. I will test that!